# mongodb array query woes

Tags: mongodb, query, mongodb-3.6

I am struggling with array matching and getting multiple records back.

```
"players" : [
    {
        "pname" : "player_4",
        "loc" : [ -2.2, 1, 0]
    },
    {
        "pname" : "player_2",
        "loc" : [ 9, 1, 5 ]
    }
]
```

Now assuming above data,

How do I project correctly where I get all the "loc" records that match the criterion?

Let's say loc.0 <15 should give both records, loc.0>0 should only give "player_2" etc.

I tried "players", "players.$". Without the $ I get all the data in "players". With the $, I get the first match. Obviously I am missing something big somewhere.

My trials below:

```
db.worlds.find({"name":"w1", "players.loc.0":{$lt:5}},{"players":1})

db.worlds.find({"name":"w1", "players.loc.0":{$lt:15}},{"players":1})

db.worlds.find({"name":"w1", "players.loc.0":{$lt:15}},{"players.$":1})
```

This is on Mongo 3.6.3.

Comment: There's a little bit of nuance here depending on what the end goal is. Is the goal to return the entire document, or only the embedded document in the 'players' array that matches the filter criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with $elemMatch :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/